# Why does std.algorithm.fill not accept character arrays?

Tags: d

If I try to use std.algorithm.fill(Range1, Range2)(Range1 range, Range2 filler), I keep getting the error message that no template match could be found. It looks like the compiler is trying to match with fill (Range, Value) rather than the other one.

```
auto test = new char[256];
fill(test, "abc".dup);
```

Is it not possible to fill a character array using fill?

The error

> test.d(13): Error: template
> std.algorithm.fill(Range,Value) if
> (isForwardRange!(Range) &&
> is(typeof(range.front = filler))) does
> not match any function template
> declaration
>
> test.d(13): Error:
> template
> std.algorithm.fill(Range,Value) if
> (isForwardRange!(Range) &&
> is(typeof(range.front = filler)))
> cannot deduce t emplate function from
> argument types !()(char[],char[])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std.algorithm.fill` takes a range. *All* string types are ranges of `dchar`. This is because they're all unicode. `char` is a UTF-8 code unit `wchar` is a UTF-16 code unit, and `dchar` is a UTF-32 code unit. Multiple code units make up a code point, which is a character. For UTF-8, a code point could be up to 6 code units. For UTF-16, it could be up to 2. For UTF-32, 1 code unit is always 1 code point, so a `dchar` is always guaranteed to be a valid character. `char` and `wchar` by themselves, however, are *not* guaranteed to be valid characters at all, and it's generally a bug if you see an individual `char` or `wchar` used. Multiple `chars` or `wchars` often must be combined to make up a single character. So, you *can't* deal with `chars` or `wchars` individually. That's why if you're iterating over a string of any kind with foreach, you should *always* give its type as `dchar`.

```
foreach(dchar c; str)
    ...
```

If you didn't specify `dchar`, then it would be whatever the character type of `str` is, which would invariably cause bugs unless `str` were an array of `dchar`, because you'd end up with code units (pieces of characters) instead of code points (whole characters). Only `dchars` can be dealt with individually.

It's because of all of this that all string types and character arrays are considered to be ranges of `dchar`, regardless of what their actual element types are. So, when you call `popFront` on a string, it could pop off a lot more than just one `char` or `wchar`. And if you call `front`, it may have to decode multiple `chars` or `wchars` to return the `dchar` that is the first character in the string. This means that you can't treat `char` or `wchar` arrays as being random access. The 4th character could be the 4th element, or it could be the 12th. And regardless of which index it starts at, it could be multiple code units long, so you can't just grab a random index in `char` or `wchar` array and expect it to be valid. So, arrays of `char` and `wchar` are *not* random access ranges. They're not output ranges either.

Think about it. Let's take the character `'\U00010143'` () for instance. It has a code unit length of 4 for UTF-8 and 2 for UTF-16. You can't just fill any random `char` or `wchar` array with it. If it's a `char` array, and its length isn't a multiple of 4, then the last ()  isn't going to fit. If it's a `wchar` array, and its length isn't a multiple of 2, then it'll have the same problem. So, it really doesn't work to use a function like `fill` on a `char` or `wchar` array.

Now, it'll work just fine with a `dchar` array. Because a UTF-32 code unit is guaranteed to be a code point, *every* character in a `dchar` array is one element, and it can be both a random access range and an output range. So, if you want to use a function like `fill` with character arrays, you need to use an array of `dchar`. You can use `std.conv.to` to convert it to the type of character array that you want after that, but you can't fill an array of `char` or `wchar` directly.

Arrays of `char` and `wchar` work great with algorithms which don't need output ranges or random access ranges, but they don't work with those. For those, you need arrays of `dchar`.

Comment: I understand about code units vs code points, but it isn't always clear to me who's responsible for the data integrity. For instance removechars insists on receiving a string, won't even accept a dstring. So I figured, that I could take responsibility for the fill function. The char[] wasn't going to contain any multibyte characters. I could have guessed that it had to do with encoding but the error message confused me. Thanks for the background.

Comment: Glancing at `removechars`, it looks like it should work with `dstring` (though for some reason, it won't accept different string types for the string and the pattern, which might be what was causing you trouble). But no range-based functions in Phobos will treat an array of `char` or `wchar` as a range of `char` or `wchar` and there aren't many (if any) which will really treat them as arrays of `char` or `wchar`. Some functions will have specializations which take advantage of the fact that they're arrays but only if it's safe and won't have issues with encodings.

Comment: Right, removechars actually accepts any string as long as the pattern type matches. That makes sense. But it will accept char[], while fill will not. I guess it's because removechars knows that the input will be convertible to dchar[], while fill cannot make that assumption and do it for you.

Comment: `removechars` isn't altering the original string. It's allocating a new one, so it can make it the appropriate length and doesn't have to worry about altering anything in place, so it can work with any character type, whereas `fill` has to alter the array which was passed to it, so it can't work with `char` or `wchar`.

Answer (score 2):

### Because typeof(test.front) == dchar, not char

It might be a bug, but it's because `typeof(test.front)` is `dchar`, not `char`, since it's interpreted as a UTF-8 string and it gives you the first Unicode character, rather than the first `char`.

#### But *why* is it interpreted that way?

One of your `import`s has probably either directly or indirectly imported a module like `std.array` (or something of that sort), whose `front()` function returns `dchar` for `char[]`. Try finding out which one it is, and instead of using that, do an `import std.iterator` instead; that one returns `char` instead of `dchar`.

Comment: There is no longer a std.iterator. I believe that it has been released in recent versions of dmd by mistake, but it has been deprecated and removed. It's not in Phobos any longer.